# Saving score into MS SQL database from Unity3D Android game

Tags: c#, android, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to save score into MS SQL database.

I've created **ASP.NET MVC** web application and when I try to call specific URL:

**www.mydomain.com/controller/action?**

whit specific parameters:

**name=somename&score=somescore**

score will be saved.

In unity **C#** script I used **WWW** API. Here is code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ShowScore : MonoBehaviour {


public string addScoreURL = "http://www.mydomain.com/controller/action?";
string score=SomeStaticClass.Score;


void Start ()
{
    string name=SystemInfo.deviceName+"_"+SystemInfo.deviceModel;
    StartCoroutine(PostScores(name,score));
}

IEnumerator PostScores(string name, int score)
{

    string post_url = addScoreURL + "name=" + WWW.EscapeURL(name) + "&score=" + score ;

    WWW hs_post = new WWW(post_url);
    yield return hs_post; // Wait until the download is done

    if (hs_post.error != null)
    {
        print("There was an error posting the high score: " + hs_post.error.ToUpper());
    }
}
```

For testing I build application for **windows**, **web** and **android**. Everything working fine for windows and web but **android** app does not save score into database.

What can be a problem?

Comment: Have you checked if the request reaches the mvc action when you use android? if it does, does it look correct?

Comment: I think request is correct because it reach the mvc action from PC and Web and there is no changes in code for android.

Answer (score 0):

Abit late to answer but using it could be a problem with your database speed

Comment: Thanks for answer. I quit with MSSQL and put everything on MySql.